# Definitions like "\def\-{…}" and footnotes

Tags: footnotes

If I use a structure like

```
\def\-{-minus-}
A\-B\footnote{A\-B}
```

then the result is the expected `A-minus-B` in the main text area, but the footnote only contains `AB`.

I did more testing, it seems that the `\def\-` declarations like the above are simply ignored in the footnotes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It is not a good idea to define a command starting with `-` symbol. Try renaming your command to start at least by one alphabetical character (Aa-Zz), e.g. `\def\a-{-minus-}`.

Comment: `\-` is reset to be `\@dischyph` when the footnote begins, so you have to either redefine again at the beginning of the footnote text, or change `\@dischyph`, both of which are a terrible idea: don't redefine `\-`: you'll get your document to behave unexpectedly

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your advice and avoid redefining \- (in the actual document I have it for **\mathchardef\myhyphen="2D**, to be used as a normally-spaced hyphen in both mathematical and text regimes).

Comment: I am sorry guys that I cannot vote for your answers: there are some weird "reputation" restrictions on this site.

Comment: The weird system is probably related to handling robots and spammers. Don't worry about as long as the question dets solved. Generally users should not use `\def` especially if you are a beginner. `\def` never warns if the macro already exists. Any macro should only be overwriting if you know exactly what the macro does. A prime example is the macro `\span` which hardly any normal latex user know the use of. Redefine it and lots of things break

Comment: The problem is that (La)TeX has already snatched many convenient one-character command names for itself. While redefining them is theoretically possibly, it is usually not advisable and can lead to weird output or catastrophic results. That's why it is a good idea to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`: `\newcommand` won't allow you to overwrite existing commands.

Comment: @hesham `\def\a-{-minus-}` doesn't define a macro with name `\a-`, it defines a command with name `\a` that must be followed by `-` (which can be quite confusing). `\-` is a valid name (the rules say that LaTeX command names consist of letters, but there is an exception for one-character commands: Those may also use non-letter commands), but the problem is that it is already taken.

Comment: @moewe Thanks I didn't know that. Actually I tried to investigate your comment, so I compiled three cases after defining `\def\a-{-minus-}`: **1.)** `A\a- B`, **2.)**  `A\a B`, and **3.)** `A\ab B`. The 1st compiled normally, the 2nd gave that error `Use of \a doesn't match its definition. A\a B`, and the 3rd gave that error `Undefined control sequence. A\ab`. So I can see now there is a difference between latex dealing with correct command name but missing followed symbol (case 2) and incorrect/undefined command name altogether (case 3).

Comment: @epR8GaYuh I suggest re-editing the question to move the `-` symbol in the code formatted `\def-` into un-formattted "declarations" to be like that "`\def` -declarations" as leaving the minus symbol with `\def` could be misleading.

Comment: Finally, I can vote, so I did my best to thank everybody :)

@hesham, sorry, I did not fully understand what editing you suggested, but I changed `\def-` in the last paragraph to `\def\-`.

@daleif, you are right that generally `\def` should be avoided, but I want a name that would not be "fully literal" for the hyphen working in both mathematical and text modes.

Your answers have clarified the situation, I will post back if I find a subjectively-suitable solution…

Comment: I should mention the *reason* that `\-` gets reset to discretionary hyphen in footnotes: LaTeX itself redefines `\-` for the tabbing environment. The tabbing redefinitions of `\-`, `\'`, `\=`, etc. have caused much grief over the years, and are commonly viewed as a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Redefining `\-` is not the best thing to do, because the command is one of the basic LaTeX ones and gets internally redefined in several places (including footnotes, as you discovered).

If your aim is to define a generic command `\g` (don't use `\a` as you initially proposed, for the same reason as `\-`), you can exploit `expl3` and `\peek_regex_replace_once:nnTF`.

This command works by looking for a match of a regular expression and, in case there is a match, the found tokens are replaced as you wish and some action can be performed on the obtained token list; in case of no match, some other code can be executed.

Here the replacement consists in bracing the matching tokens, so the function `\curious_g:n` can act on them. The working of `\curious_g:n` should be clear. Note that you can even use multiple characters following `\g`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathhyphen}{\mathord}{operators}{"2D}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\g}{}
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nnTF
   { ( \- | \= | \+ | \!\= ) } % look for
   { \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }          % replace with
   { \curious_g:n }            % do if match
   { \BAD }                    % do if no match
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \curious_g:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {-}{\mathhyphen}
    {=}{\equiv}
    {+}{\oplus}
    {!=}{\not\equiv}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a \g- b$
$a \g= b$
$a \g+ b$
$a \g!= b$
$a \g? b $ % error
${\g}$     % error

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\BAD` you should use something more informative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above discussion makes it clear that redefining `\-` is a bad idea.

Nevertheless, I need "my versions" of some characters, and here is my solution: basically, it is in the flavour of `\def\a-{-minus-}` mentioned above, but it reuses the one-letter literal command (I changed it to `\g`) for multiple characters:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

\mathchardef\myhyphen="2D

\newcommand{\g}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}-}{\myhyphen}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}=}{\equiv}{}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}+}{\oplus}{}%
}
```

The result can be seen via `$\g+ \g= \g-$`: it suits my needs.